# mean() giving NA error on numeric and complete data

Tags: r

Sample data

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
Sessions <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 3000, sd = 300))
Registrations <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 800, sd = 100))
Conversions <- ceiling(rnorm(50, mean = 400, sd = 50))
Date_Range = seq(Sys.Date() - 50, Sys.Date() - 1, by = 1)
sample_data <- data.frame(Date_Range,Sessions, Registrations, Conversions)
sample_data <- tbl_df(sample_data)
```

A function:

```
dataByDates <- function(startDate, endDate, metric) {
      filter(sample_data, Date_Range >= startDate & Date_Range <= endDate) %>% select_(metric)
    }
```

Try the function with sum:

```
sum(aggByDates(Sys.Date()-1, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions"))gives 2975.
```

So far so good.

But:

```
> mean(aggByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions"))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(aggByDates(Sys.Date() - 10, Sys.Date() - 1, metric = "Sessions")) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

It's a complete set of numeric data, should not even have to use na.rm = TRUE (and I did try it for sanity, adding na.rm+T never made a difference)

See

```
> str(aggByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions"))
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Sessions: num  2792 2938 2621 3651 3363 ...
```

And

```
> table(complete.cases(aggByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions")))

TRUE 
  10
```

So if I have complete numeric data, why am I getting this error and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `mean` doesn't work on a data frame. The error is the same as:

```
mean(data.frame(A = 1:3))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data.frame(A = 1:3)) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

`dplyr` *select* returns a data frame, but `mean` is not defined for a data frame, from `?mean`, here is about the argument *x*:

> An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors
>   and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are
>   allowed for trim = 0, only.

Same reason `sum` works fine, because:

```
sum(data.frame(A = 1:3))
[1] 6
```

works. (The behavior might seem unconformably inconsistent here.)

---

If you like the function to work for both `sum` and `mean`, a better way might be returning a vector from the function:

```
dataByDates <- function(startDate, endDate, metric) {
      filter(sample_data, Date_Range >= startDate & Date_Range <= endDate)[[metric]]
    }
```

Now, both `mean` and `sum` work as expected:

```
sum(dataByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions"))
[1] 29979

mean(dataByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions"))
[1] 2997.9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the column and get the `mean`

```
aggByDates(Sys.Date()-10, Sys.Date()-1, metric = "Sessions") %>% 
                 .$Sessions %>%
                  mean
#[1] 2997.9
```

Comment: Thanks (again!). The already accepted answer is dynamic in the $metric part which is also desirable